# How are the best practices to implement network calls on a comments screen on Android?

Tags: java, android, connection, retrofit

I have to do a comments screen, and I don't want to block the user while the network call is running, so, I am thinking about how can I manage a way where the user can write something, click the send button, and repeat this process lots of times, putting the items in the comments list, then making the calls and if it failed, shows a try again button just in the items where the fail happens. What I'm thinking to do, is, create a recursive method to treat the call, and every time the user click the send button, I add the comment to a list, and the call method will do itself until the list is empty. But, if the fail happens just for one comment, for example, how can I know the comment where I have to show the try again button? And, there's a better way to do this? I'm using Retrofit.

Comment: Actually I want to do a kind of stack of calls, to execute in sequence a lot of calls.

Comment: @FoamyGuy AsyncTask isn't the only solution for multi-threading.  For regularly repeated work it actually has several bad qualities-  either you run them in parallel meaning the order they execute in can get swapped, or they end up filling the queue starving other parts of your app which may use AsyncTask.  It also makes things difficult to batch requests.  Sometimes the right answer is to use a Thread.

Answer (score 0):

THe standard way of doing this is to create a Thread and have a synchronized list of messages to send.  When you press a button, you add an item to the list.  The thread will have an infinite loop, reading the top item from the list (or sleeping until its non-empty) and processing it (sending it to the server in this case).